# ckfinder thumbnails slow

Tags: ckfinder

We are using the paid version of `CKFinder`. When we open the pop-up we see our complete structured folder with all images, but it takes ages to load.

This is due too `CKFinder` and not our server. If I would have coded my own "finder" it would almost load images instantly, because the deadline I couldnt code it myself and thus we decided to use `CKFinder` but as said, it is horribly slow.

Is there any way to speed up the process so we dont have to wait seconds every single time we go to a new folder? some folders take almost `10 seconds` to load, and yes... there are 50+ images in the folder but as said. I made a small script that does the same as `CKFinder` and it loads everything almost instantly. But since we paid for `CKfinder` we want to use this, but reduce the load times.

As said, if I would have coded my own finder there would almost be no delay compared to CKFinder.

I hope someone knows how to speed up `CKfinder` :)

Comment: A few questions: Which version of CKFinder do you use? Is it slow for local or remote backend? On which browser it's slow?

Comment: Each CKFinder license comes with direct support from CKFinder developers. Please [use the support channel](https://cksource.com/contact) and add more details (including [what zaak asked you above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711876/ckfinder-thumbnails-slow#comment61010839_36711876)) about the version you are using, your configuration etc. Loading 50 thumbnails should not take 10 seconds, so it's possible there is something wrong with your configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your responce :D

We implemented this last week so it should be the latest version of CKFinder 3.

My config file is here below. If no one on here knows a fix, I most definitely will contact the CKFinder makers. We indeed have 1 year of support with our licence as you stated :)

Code: http://paste.ofcode.org/AkNn4fhiuXiLcSjfzvb9uA

Sorry I didnt paste the code here, kept giving me an error :(

Comment: What browser doesnt matter, tried Firefox, Chrome, Yandex, Edge, IE, Safari and Opera.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small problem in your `config.php` that may make CKFinder slow: the `default` backend is a remote one (FTP), and it's used in the [`privateDir`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_privateDir) section as a backend to store CKFinder private files (including generated thumbnails). Fetching data from FTP is much slower in comparison with the local file system, and this may cause delays. The way to solve this is creating an additional backend in the local file system and use it as a storage for private data in the `privateDir` section.

Example:

```php
$config['privateDir'] = array(
    'backend' => 'ckfinder_private_data', // Use the local file system backend.
    'tags'   => '.ckfinder/tags',
    'logs'   => '.ckfinder/logs',
    'cache'  => '.ckfinder/cache',
    'thumbs' => '.ckfinder/cache/thumbs',
);

$config['backends'][] = array(
    'name'    => 'ckfinder_private_data',
    'adapter' => 'local',
    'root'    => '/path/to/writable/dir/'
);
```

Additionally, you may also try lowering [`thumbnailDelay`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Config-cfg-thumbnailDelay) in the CKFinder JavaScript client.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will give this a try later and will let you know how it worked out. Thanks so much for your answer!